# How does mass spectroscopy of nicotine work?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

Take this nicotine molecule:

[image]

And this mass spectrum:

[image]

I'm not sure how to explain all the peaks.

This might explain the peak at 42:

[image]

But can this peek als be explained by something else in the molecule?

Like the decomposition of the ring with the double bonds:
[image]

This might explain the peak at 84:

[image]

And I'm clueless on the peak at 133

Answer (score 1):

The peak at 133 corresponds to a loss of 29 mass units (nicotine is 162).  N-CH3 has a mass of 29

Comment: How about the others? Do you think my guesses were correct?

Comment: How can you know whether the peak at 42 is the decomposition of the ring with the double bonds or the ring without the double bonds?

Comment: Yes, I think your other guesses are reasonable.  As Klaus points out, you would need to look at the mass spectrum of some model compounds and/or some isotopically labeled compounds to know for sure.  Also, especially in larger molecules, if you have a high resolution mass spectrometer that can help, because if you calculate the mass to 6 decimal places, different fragments with the same mass - but different formula - will give rise to different exact masses.  As to which ring is fragmenting, the pyridine ring is aromatic and therefor has more stability then the saturated

Comment: pyrolidine ring, making the pyridine less likely to crack.

Comment: "pyrolidine ring, making the pyridine less likely to crack" How can you explain the fact that altghouh stable, there is no peak in the MS for 78... I would expect it to be the base peak.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your assignment is reasonable.

As ron has already pointed out, cleavage of an endocyclic $\ce{C-N}$ bond (= opening of the pyrolidine ring) in nicotine is likely. The resulting open chain fragment then loses $\ce{NCH3}$.

The peak at 84 represents a N-methylpyrolidine fragment and indicates that the bond between the two heterocycles is cleaved. This also makes sense.

In general, it it a good idea to work from higher to lower masses and not to spend to much brain on the very small fragments.

Comment: How can you know whether the peak at 42 is the decomposition of the ring with the double bonds or the ring without the double bonds?

Comment: @Pickering You might be able to rule that out by comparison with the MS of pyridine. Further experimental proof could involve the specific isotopic labelling of the starting material.